# django framework can't see new model online

Tags: python, django

I have to make some modification to a website built with the django framework (version 1.6).

The problem I am having is that I can not transfer the modification I made offline to the online server. I can see the new page, the database has been modified, but in the administration website the new category I created does not appear, thus i can not fill the fields with the new information.

The steps I went through are:

1. create the new model in models.py,
2. import the model in admin.py,
3. execute the command: `touch wsgi.py`

in order to reload the file.

In the offline version everything is working fine. I do not know that to do!

Code I added in admin.py file (I added the "Article" section):

```
from active.models import x, z, y, j, Article

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ["title"]
    list_display = ('title',)
    search_fields = ['title']

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

Comment: which server are you running your site behind and in what mode is it serving? do you have to restart it?https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Comment: Yes i did the migration with the syncdb command.
I can see the new table in the database!

The web server I'm using is apache, and i did not touch anything of the configuration!

Comment: What does your admin.py look like?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

There was no problem at all, simply the user I access the administration site with did not have the right access to see the new section!

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported `admin` in the admin.py file?

```
from django.contrib import admin
```

Comment: I would ask this in a comment, but I'm a n00b.

Comment: Yes i have imported it. There are other several section in the admin.py file, and they all works!

Comment: Do you have any page caching that might be affecting it?

Comment: And you've restarted apache?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: No, I did not restart apache!

Comment: Try restarting apache.